# Slider inside a Google Map info bubble not working first time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, slider

I am using Google map info bubble and inside the info bubble I show a slider which works fine only after the second click of an marker when i click first time the slider does not work even though i gave it on the domready like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
   initialize();  
   google.maps.event.addListener(infoBubble, 'domready', function(){
    // initiate slider here
       jQuery('.map_slider').each(function(){ 
        var slid_id = (this.id);alert('in'+slid_id);
        jQuery("#"+slid_id).easySlider({nextId: ""+slid_id+"next",prevId: ""+slid_id+"prev",prevText:'<img src="images/prev.png" />',nextText:'<img src="images/next.png" />',tempstr:slid_id,continuous: true });
    });
   });   
});
```

the alert will come only after the second click. Please help me to get out from this issue

Comment: Did you check the Script console? What does it say?

Comment: @Cthulhu yes i checked but does not show any error. the event is not triggered  first time

Comment: The infoWindow is probably  not created by the time jQuery(document).ready() fires. Please post a more complete section of your code or a link to a live demo.

Answer (score 1):

The infoWindow is probably  not created by the time `jQuery(document).ready()` fires. Please post a more complete section of your code or a link to a live demo.Otherwise,  try creatiung the infowindow as a global variable, outside of function initialize():

```
var infoBubble = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {    
       initialize(); 
       google.maps.event.addListener(infoBubble, 'domready', function(){
        // initiate slider here
           jQuery('.map_slider').each(function(){ 
            var slid_id = (this.id);alert('in'+slid_id);
            jQuery("#"+slid_id).easySlider({nextId: ""+slid_id+"next",prevId: ""+slid_id+"prev",prevText:'<img src="images/prev.png" />',nextText:'<img src="images/next.png" />',tempstr:slid_id,continuous: true });
        });
       });   
    });
```